# Powershell manage set of variables

Tags: powershell

It should be ok to add all the variables as global inside the function? All the other functions will receive them? I did a short test and it should work. Should I need to add Get-Variable -ValueOnly...?

```
$ReleaseVersion = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).ReleaseVersion
$Sourceversion = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).Sourceversion
$LinkForVersion = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).LinkForVersion
$VersionNumber = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).VersionNumber
$buildver = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).buildver
$PipelineID = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).PipelineID
$xmlFilePath = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).xmlFilePath
$ReleaseBuildVer = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).ReleaseBuildVer

Set-Variable -Name "ReleaseVersion" -Value $ReleaseVersion -Scope global
Set-Variable -Name "Sourceversion" -Value $Sourceversion -Scope global
Set-Variable -Name "LinkForVersion" -Value $LinkForVersion -Scope global
Set-Variable -Name "VersionNumber" -Value $VersionNumber -Scope global
Set-Variable -Name "buildver" -Value $buildver -Scope global
Set-Variable -Name "PipelineID" -Value $PipelineID -Scope global
Set-Variable -Name "xmlFilePath" -Value $xmlFilePath -Scope global
Set-Variable -Name "ReleaseBuildVer" -Value $ReleaseBuildVer -Scope global

}
```

I have a script that read from excel collect files according to a column, Before the running I need to define 4 variables, the issue is that I need to run it for several versions. That means that for each run I need to leave active 4 variables and the rest should be in comment (#) and I do it manually (need to add 12 times #
There is a smart way to choose all the 4 variables per version?

I will give an example:

[image]

Each time only one set is enabled (According to version I want to work on)

The using of those parameters are:

```
Add-VSTeamWorkItem -ProjectName "Client-Server" -Title "[Side VIP] [$VersionNumber]"

$Versionlocationforpatches = "$Sourceversion\Installer\Patches" 
$Versionlocationforcabs = "$Sourceversion\Installer" 

Add-VSTeamBuild -ProjectName "Client-Server" -BuildDefinitionId $PipelineID

function RenameVerFile ([string] $buildver) 
{
    $DefaultFile = Get-ChildItem $Sourceversion | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "BuildVer.txt"}
    Clear-Content $DefaultFile.FullName -Force 
    $Newcontent = Add-Content $DefaultFile.FullName -Value ($buildver + "." + (Get-Random)) 
    
}
```

Some of them are using in other places

Now I have something like this and I am very happy but I want to display the user a menu like:
For version 8.5.34 choose 1, Without insert manually the number

[image]

I hope this will do the job

```
do {$VersionToUse = $Versions.buildver | Out-Gridview -Title "Choose version" -PassThru } while ($Versions.buildver -notcontains $VersionToUse)
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to _parameterize_ your script :) Can you show an example of the 4 variables you currently define at the top of the script?

Comment: Each variable is used in the script. For an example $var1 is the path of the version $var2 is the title of the tag item $var3 is the is the pipeline  id.  for each run I need to active every time another 4 parameters

Comment: And how are they used? Do you pass them as arguments to one or more functions/commands? (hint: it would be a lot easier to help you if you posted your script)

Comment: I will add the script. I have 1000 rows…. I pass them to functions and commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Totally Changed this answer to include latest information

User of the script will now see versions to select and then enter version number to be used. your four variables are then filled with the relevant data.

```
$SharedDriveFolderPath= "\\Test\xxx" # This is just for me to test - you have your own data somewhere
$Versions = @()
$Versions += "VersionNumber;Sourceversion;PipelineID;buildvers;"
$Versions += "8.5.34;$SharedDriveFolderPath\Versions\8.5.34.31;18710;8.5.34.31"
$Versions += "8.5.35;$SharedDriveFolderPath\Versions\8.5.34.35;18713;8.5.34.35"
$Versions = $Versions | ConvertFrom-CSV -Del ";"

do {$VersionToUse = ($Versions | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title "Select version to use").VersionNumber} while (-not $VersionToUse)

$VersionNumber = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).VersionNumber
$Sourceversion = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).Sourceversion
$PipelineID = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).PipelineID
$buildvers = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).buildvers
```

Take this Code to replace your version lines (the ones you posted here as screenshot example)

Alternative as json if you prefer that:

```
$SharedDriveFolderPath= "\\Test\xxx" # This is just for me to test - you have your own data somewhere
$Versions = @"
[
    {
        "VersionNumber":  "8.5.34",
        "Sourceversion":  "$($SharedDriveFolderPath -replace "\\","\\")\\Versions\\8.5.34.31",
        "PipelineID":  "18710",
        "buildvers":  "8.5.34.31"
    },
    {
        "VersionNumber":  "8.5.35",
        "Sourceversion":  "$($SharedDriveFolderPath -replace "\\","\\")\\Versions\\8.5.34.35",
        "PipelineID":  "18713",
        "buildvers":  "8.5.34.35"
    }
]
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

do {$VersionToUse = ($Versions | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title "Select version to use").VersionNumber} while (-not $VersionToUse)

$VersionNumber = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).VersionNumber
$Sourceversion = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).Sourceversion
$PipelineID = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).PipelineID
$buildvers = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).buildvers
```

Replace the line starting with "do" with the following code to get another way of selection if you don't like the gridview

```
$i = 0; foreach ($Version in $Versions.VersionNumber) {$i++; "[$i] $Version"; }; $VersionToUse = ($Versions[$(do {"Enter ID of Version to use"; $id = Read-Host} while (-not ($id -le $Versions.count -and $id -gt 0));$id - 1)]).VersionNumber
```

Comment: I don't have configuration file.

Comment: Where do you have the variables you Show in the Screenshot?

Comment: On the top I have 4 variables X 3 versions
I want to change only one variable in one place for each version and not changing manually all the four.
Or even better if I ask the user on which version he wants to work on:
1 for 8.5.34
2 for 8.5.35

After he choose the right version the corresponding variables will  define

Comment: For today i can not update the code, but you could offload the variables as showed in your screenshot and use my script as it is. Just move the content to a new file and include it like ". .\VersionDataFile.ps1"

Comment: I will be grateful if you will update the code because I don't  understand how to use it
Thank you
The user will have the option to choose on which version to work on?

Comment: Need to use this also?
$myVars = @{}
$myVars.Version2000 = @{"Path"="c:\";"Title"="MySensitiveData"}
$myVars.Version2000.Path
$myVars.Version2000.Title

Comment: Can you elaborate what files should I need to create? What should be in the ps1 and txt files and how I call them

Comment: i guess it should be clear now what to do and i hope that is what you need

Comment: Thank you very much. There is an option to let the user to choose from a list? Instead of let him insert the version manually? Like 1 for: 8.5.34 and in the next row 2 for: 8.5.35

Comment: The key here is $VersionNumber?
On base what the version is selected?

Comment: The list would be easy If you use Out-Gridview for $Versions.VersionNumber and pass the selection to $VersionToUse wich is the variable used to detect wich data is for the four variables you need.

Comment: Thank you An-dir
Can you help me with that? :)

Comment: I don't know how to do it and when to place it in the script

Comment: The line $Versions = $Versions | ConvertFrom-CSV -Del ";" shows all the parameters. I would like to show only the buildver (4 rows) and let the user to choose (Not to insert manually)
1. 8.5.34
2. 8.5.35
3. 8.6.22

And he will insert 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: Changed one line to fit your needs.

Comment: One more question please. The function is working and getting the parameters but all the variables set only in this function. I need to pass the. to another function. How can I do that?

Comment: I updated the script regarding my last question. 
It should be ok to add all the variables as global inside the function? All the other functions will receive them?

Comment: a global scope might do what you want it to. you should learn more about powershell if you use it in production as you might get unexpected behaviour within a running and living environment. you always should at least take a short look at the documentation. Here i have a link for you about scopes (global is one) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2   Also look at using-dot-source-notation-with-scope on the same site which might affect how you can use your variables

Answer (score 0):

You could store and choose it that way with a hashtable:

```
$myVars = @{}
$myVars.Version2000 = @{"Path"="c:\";"Title"="MySensitiveData"}
$myVars.Version2000.Path
$myVars.Version2000.Title
```

it could then look like

```
PS C:\> $myVars = @{}
PS C:\> $myVars.Version2000 = @{
>> "Path"="c:\Prog2000"
>> "Title"="MySensitiveData"
>> "Var3"="Value3"
>> "Var4"="value4"
>> }
PS C:\> $myVars.Version2013 = @{
>> "Path"="c:\Prog2013"
>> "Title"="MySensitiveData"
>> "Var3"="Value3"
>> "Var4"="value4"
>> }
PS C:\> $myVars.Version2000

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Var4                           value4
Path                           c:\
Var3                           Value3
Title                          MySensitiveData
PS C:\> $myVars.Version2000.Path
c:\
```

EDIT: Added a new answer as more information came in OP

Comment: Thank you An-dir for your answer. I edited the question. I don't know if I can use your solution. If it down please tell me how, Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your update, but i am still unsure if i understood it correctly :D